# Constraints Buttons on LayerView AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

I am trying to successfully align 2 `UIButton` laying on **TOP** of a `layerView`.

The hierarchy is as following:

[image]

The Buttons lay just on top of the layerView (Just a UIView which is black and has a certain alpha).
Now I want the buttons to align within this "container".

Like this:

[image]

I was setting the `constraints` to the left and top + to the right and top. also kept aspect ratio.

This was the result:

[image]

So it is just the buttons making problems.
Anyone knows another way of solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Embed the buttons inside a `UIView`
2. Set the `UIView` to have fixed width and height
3. Set `UIView` to horizontally align to Center.
4. since the "Layer View" has a dynamic height, set the UIView's bottom space to "Layer View"

Answer (score 2):

Try putting both the layer and the buttons inside of a parent `UIView`, then have your layer fill up that view and the buttons centered vertically inside it.